# Show Pyramid Pattern in the Label

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have a codes here for console

```
int numberoflayer = 6, Space, Number;
Console.WriteLine("Print paramid");
for (int i = 1; i <= numberoflayer; i++) // Total number of layer for pramid
{
   for (Space = 1; Space <= (numberoflayer - i); Space++)  // Loop For Space
        Console.Write(" ");
   for (Number = 1; Number <= i; Number++) //increase the value
        Console.Write('*');
   for (Number = (i - 1); Number >= 1; Number--)  //decrease the value
        Console.Write('*');
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

But I want to show that in C# windows form label. I have a lbl_result;

I don't know how can I add this in my Form1_Load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_result.Text = // how can I execute the loop pyramid here
}
```

Comment: Just some helpful advice, you should camel case variable names.  Capitalized words like that are usually reserved for class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move this code to separated method that returns `string` and set it as text.

Like this:

```
  public string GetPyramid() 
  { 
       int numberoflayer = 6, Space, Number;
        string result = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberoflayer; i++) // Total number of layer for pramid
            {
               for (Space = 1; Space <= (numberoflayer - i); Space++)  // Loop For Space
                   result += " ";
               for (Number = 1; Number <= i; Number++) //increase the value
                    result += "*";
               for (Number = (i - 1); Number >= 1; Number--)  //decrease the value
                    result += "*";
                    result += "\n";
            } 

        return result;
    }
```

However `numberOfLayers` should be parameter to this method. I don't know what `Space` and `Number` are so it's hard to sort it out for you. Basically idea is to put it to separated method that returns string. I also didn't check your loops, because I assume it does what you expecting after checking results in `Console`.

Then just use it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_result.Text = GetPyramid();
}
```

Comment: It on gives me. * *** *******

Comment: just add result += "\n"; after last excecution.

Comment: Add new line character after each line \n

Answer (score 0):

Change `Console` to `StringBuilder`; `Write` to `Append` and `WriteLine` to `AppendLine`:

```
int numberoflayer = 6, Space, Number;

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.AppendLine("Print paramid");
for (int i = 1; i <= numberoflayer; i++) // Total number of layer for pramid
{
   for (Space = 1; Space <= (numberoflayer - i); Space++)  // Loop For Space
        builder.Append(" ");
   for (Number = 1; Number <= i; Number++) //increase the value
        builder.Append('*');
   for (Number = (i - 1); Number >= 1; Number--)  //decrease the value
        builder.Append('*');
        builder.AppendLine();
}

lbl_result.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int numberoflayer = 6, Space, Number;
string str = "Print paramid";
str += "\n";
for (int i = 1; i <= numberoflayer; i++) // Total number of layer for pramid
{
    for (Space = 1; Space <= (numberoflayer - i); Space++) // Loop For Space
        str += " ";
    for (Number = 1; Number <= i; Number++) //increase the value
        str += '*';
    for (Number = (i - 1); Number >= 1; Number--) //decrease the value
        str += '*';
    str += "\n";
}

lbl_result.Text = str;
```

Concatenate your string variable `str` using the `+=` operator.

You can also use [`String.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) or [`StringBuilder.Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8.aspx) method.